# Job interviewer going dark?

Tags: interviewing, job-search

I had an interview at a company for a lead position. I gave the interview and the director said that the HR will be contacting me for behavioral based interview. I didn't hear back from them so I sent a follow up email a week later asking about it. He didn't respond back. Out of the blue, one month later, he came back apologizing for not responding earlier and wondering if I am still interested. Is it worth proceeding? It seems that they are not taking any interest in the interview process.
P.S: I have had interview loops for 3 months but haven't experienced 1 month communication gap.

Comment: It could be anything. Perhaps somebody was ill?

Comment: Is it a large company or a smaller one? Large companies tend to have very long processes especially for higher positions. Otherwise unless there was a sick leave or summer vacation involved, I would consider a one month break a red flag (possibly struggling financially but needing to fill the position - maybe the previous lead quit due to those reasons?).

Comment: Well you don't know the situation. Holidays, sickness, pending answer client-side or from another applicant,... Many things could explain this situation. Apologizing at least shows they aknowledge this was a long wait. So I wouldn't consider this a no-go as such, but you don't share much information about your global feeling about the company or the job, and that is anyway a choice only you canmake in the end.

Comment: Something like this happened to a company where I work. We hire somebody, we wait for his two weeks notice at his employer then he left after a week at our company. So we had to offer the job to second top candidate after a month gap.

Comment: Simply you got passed over the first time(probably better candidate) but now they have an opening and are willing to consider you for it.  do you want it?

Comment: In my experience in most cases this means a certain level of inefficiency or dysfunctionality in a company. Not always, but best to move on. Certain specific roles can have a very long processing time but otherwise it tells you more about the company than about yourself per se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a large company, there may still be internal infighting going on.

> Are we going to hire contractors?  Are we going to hire for full-time?  Are we going to have a mix?  Do we have all the real estate and equipment ready?  What?  Another 3 week delay?  How are they going to work without computers?  We're going to need five more people agree to telecommuting in order to have available cubes.  Did anyone ever fix the line to cube 3C, or is that one still dead?  We can't hire them until 3 EVPs sign off on this!

There can be any number of things going on in the background that can cause delays.  Now this could be a good or bad thing.  EITHER, they are so disorganized that they don't know what they're doing, or they are so short handed that grabbing people to make decisions is difficult.  Keep following up until you either get a solid "YES" or "NO".  If nothing else, it will give you experience in the process, at best they could be impressed with your dogged persistence.